# Cannot open Emacs as a window

Tags: 14.04, emacs

I am new to Ubuntu and am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.  I installed Emacs 25.2.  When I use the emacs command, the files are directly opened in terminal and I cannot open emacs window.

I used these commands to install it:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install build-essential  
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24  
cd ~/Downloads  
wget "http://gnu.mirrors.hoobly.com/gnu/emacs/emacs-25.2.tar.gz"  
tar xvzf emacs-25.2.tar.gz  
cd emacs-25.2  
./configure --without-x  
make  
sudo make install
```

Comment: Installed how . . . ?

Comment: Well obviously if you configure it `--without-x` you won't get the GUI (X Windows) version. BTW you should [edit] your question with the above information instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: I am new user, thank you. So which commands should I use to reinstall it? @steeldriver

Comment: Since you are a new user, I'd strongly recommend you install the provided version from the repository (either via the Software Center or `sudo apt-get install emacs`). On 14.04 that should get you emacs version 24.3 built with the Gtk GUI.

Comment: I installed 24.3, just configure it and problem solved. Thank you very much! @steeldriver